# ajax keeps posting outdated value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form that auto submits and updates the same page. I have a java script function that changes a buttons value, but AJAX keeps posting the old value.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.action,
            data: $('form').serialize()
});
```

JQUERY

```
function changevalue()
{
 $('#button').attr('value', 'grapes');
}
```

FORM

```
form...
<input type="submit"  name="button" id="button" value="apple" onclick="changevalue();" />
...
```

Button will display new changed word, but code behind (controller) shows old variable.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on multiple browsers, or is it browser specific?

Comment: Yes. IE,Chrome and Firefox. cleared cache, restarted. No fix

Comment: How are you calling that Ajax line? You are not showing that in your code sample above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value using jQuery's `.val()` method.

```
function changevalue() {
    $('#button').val('grapes');
}
```

As of jQuery 1.6.0, the `.attr()` method correctly stopped accessing and changing property values, it only changes attributes.

Comment: Same issue. Button updates to the new word "grapes" but code behind has old posted value.

Comment: @user999690 jQuery's `.serialize` method doesn't seem to even send inputs of `type="submit"` http://jsfiddle.net/9LnCz/ you may need to use another method of sending that value, such as a hidden input or building the data to send manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are not cancelling the submit button's default action clicking on that button, it is refreshing the page which means the default value will reappear.

Add event handlers with code, not inline markup.

```
<input type="submit"  name="button" id="button" value="apple" />

<script>
    $( function() {  
        $("#button").on("click", changevalue); //assign the click for 1.7+
        //$("#button").click( changevalue); //assign the click for 1.6.x and below
    });

    function changevalue(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); //cancel the click action
        $(this).val("grapes");  //set the value with val, do not use attr
    }
</script>
```

And from the docs on [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. **No
>   submit button value is serialized** since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.